# Bootstrap Toggle with BootstrapDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-dialog

Excuse me,

Is it possible to show [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#demos) in `message` field of [BootstrapDialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)?

For example:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Information',
  message: '<input class="toggleExample" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">'
});
```

Also, I tried to initialize `$('.toggleExample')` before BootstrapDialog and after BootstrapDialog, but they all didn't work.

Comment: looks like the bootstrap 3 is required for dialog plugin and bootstrap 2 for toggle, so there is no common bootstrap version between the plugins, so you cant use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BootStrap dialog` plugin is built on bootstrap 3 library similarly  `Bootstrap dialog` is built on bootstrap 2 library.

so both the plugins work with different versions of core library, hence you cannot combine features of both plugins.

**For more info refer plugins official site:**

- Bootstrap Dialog - https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog
- Bootstrap Toggle (go to end of the page to know the version) - http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just try this Code for your need, This will Popup with the Checkbox and Button.

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: function (dialogItself) {
        var $form = $('<form></form>');
        var $titleDrop = $('<input type="checkbox" />');
        dialogItself.setData('field-title-drop', $titleDrop);   // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
        $form.append('<label>Click Here</label>').append($titleDrop);

        return $form;
    },
    buttons: [{
        label: 'OK.',
        action: function (dialogItself) {
            alert(dialogItself.getData('field-title-drop').val());
        }
    }]
});
```

Try this Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7DcHW/30/